# how can i change the color property with if else condition flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, colors, flutter-layout

Hello i created a custom BottomNavigationBar in flutter and want to use a if else condition in the color property of the IconButton.
Does anyone know what is the mistake ?

```
enum Pages {
  home,
  folder,
}

Pages selectPage = Pages.home

Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                selectPage = Pages.home;
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: selectPage == Pages.home
                    ? activeButtonColor
                    : inactiveButtonColor,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: size.width * 0.20),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                selectPage = Pages.folder;
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.folder,
                color: selectPage == Pages.folder
                    ? activeButtonColor
                    : inactiveButtonColor,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Call setState on `onPressed` to update the UI. Make sure to use `StatefulWidget` widget and `selectPage` outside the build method.

```dart
onPressed: () {
  selectPage = Pages.home;
  setState(() { });
},
```

More about [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer but my problem is the selectPage property next the color: of the icon is underlined in red

Comment: It means you didn't create these variables `activeButtonColor` & or `inactiveButtonColor` or forgot to import these, also make sure it is a `Color` object. If you failed, include full widget or the place you've defined theses